# Can Nginx substring the $request_uri?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I want to substring $request_uri
For example, The URL address is:https://example/surveyssl/survey
If I using $request_uri, it will get "surveyssl/survey"
Can I substring "surveyssl" so that I can get "survey" only?

```
location /surveyssl/survey{
             proxy_pass http://ssldev/surveyssl/index.php/$request_uri;
             #It will fail because the url output is 
             #http://ssldev/surveyssl/index.php/surveyssl/survey
             #but I want to get this url:
             #http://ssldev/surveyssl/index.php/survey
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown sample, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. First ruleset is very specific one to catch only surveyssl; 2nd rules set it dynamic one where it will catch anything coming after surveyssl.

```
location ~ /surveyssl/(survey/?) {
             proxy_pass http://ssldev/surveyssl/index.php/$1;

 }
```

***EDIT:*** To make it dynamic try following rules:

```
location ~ /surveyssl/([\w-]+/?) {
             proxy_pass http://ssldev/surveyssl/index.php/$1;

 }
```

Comment: @龍が如く, ok could you please try my edited solution now?

Comment: Still cannot run

Comment: @龍が如く, please do let me know what's the error you are getting?

Comment: This nginx is run on docker container, if there have error, it will  Exited (1)

Comment: @龍が如く, Ok, 1 more try, I have edited my rules now, could you please do check my edited rules once and let me know if this helps you now?

Comment: It is fail too. But I find that if remove the dollar sign on location, container can run normally

Comment: @龍が如く, sure, you mean like edited one? Please check it once, this considers your url is something like `http://localhost:80/surveyssl/survey`, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @龍が如く, actually `$` means it looks for url ending with `survey` OR `survey/` so I have removed it; to now match with only `http://localhost:80/surveyssl/survey`.

Comment: It works now. But actually I want to make it dynamic, for example, I have 'location /surveyssl/survey', 'location /surveyssl/thank', 'location /surveyssl/help', 'location /surveyssl/document'.... etc. If I can get the word behind "surveyssl", no need set to many role for proxy_pass

Comment: @龍が如く, sure, could you please do check my EDIT rules now and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Yes, this is right and work. Thanks for your help

Comment: @龍が如く, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning.